# print just the key of I in dict

Tags: python

so I am writing a program that when you give it a dictionary value it turns you it's key . the program consist of by giving the score of an allergy it tells you what allergy you got . I wrote the script but returns me None as result to my function . Can someone tell me what I should modify ?

```
def allergie(aller):
    listofallergies = {'eggs': 1 , 'peanuts':2 ,'shellfish': 4 , 'strawberries':8 , 'tomatoes': 16 , 'chocolat':32 , 'pollen': 64 , 'cats': 128 }
    if aller in listofallergies:
        print (listofallergies.keys(aller))
    else:
        return None 
print (allergie(4))
```

Comment: `print (listofallergies.keys(aller))` --> `return listofallergies.keys(aller)`

Comment: A comment on naming practice: if something is not a list don't call it a list. Call it `allgergies_dict` or something like that.

Comment: I find it suspicious that the values are all powers of two: Isn't this a bit-map, and you can be given e.g. `5` for "shellfish and eggs"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem would be that first if branch doesn't return nothing, it only prints. Secondly the logic is wrong `if item in dict` checks if `item` is a key in the `dict`, here as you have a value, you need to iterate on the pairs, to check the value and return the key if matches

```
def allergie(aller):
    listofallergies = {'eggs': 1, 'peanuts': 2, 'shellfish': 4, 'strawberries': 8,
                       'tomatoes': 16, 'chocolat': 32, 'pollen': 64, 'cats': 128}
    for key, value in listofallergies.items():
        if value == aller:
            return key
    return None

print(allergie(4))  # shellfish
print(allergie(40))  # None
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't return anything if `aller in listofallergies`, just print. Also, `aller in listofallergies` will never be True, because that's not how you check if something is in the `.values()` of a dict.

Returning `None` is also not necessary if it is not in the dict — a function will return that automatically by default.

Since `some_dict.keys()` doesn't take an argument, as you seem to assume, you will need to iterate over all values and check if they are equal to the given value.

Here's how you could fix it:

```
def allergie(aller):
    listofallergies = {'eggs': 1 , 'peanuts':2 ,'shellfish': 4 , 'strawberries':8 , 'tomatoes': 16 , 'chocolat':32 , 'pollen': 64 , 'cats': 128 }
    if aller in listofallergies.values():
        for key, item in listofallergies.items():
            if item == aller:
                return key  # we found it, so we return it.
```

Frankly, you could also skip checking `if aller in listofallergies.values()` entirely, but maybe it's clearer this way.

---

If there's no good reason not to do this, why don't you just invert the dictionary? Then the function just becomes:

```
def allergie(aller):
    return {1: "eggs", 2: "peanuts", 4: "shellfish", ...}.get(aller)
```

---

Finally, if this is indeed a bitmap, and you want to in fact return the *list* of allergies encoded in a given value, you can do so with bitwise arithmetics:

```
def allergies(allergy_code):
    result = []
    for index, allergy in enumerate(['eggs', 'peanuts','shellfish', 'strawberries', 'tomatoes', 'chocolat', 'pollen', 'cats']):
        if allergy_code & 2**index:
            result.append(allergy)
    return result

>>> allergies(5)
['eggs', 'shellfish']
```

Answer (score 1):

I would invert the dictionary once and then just use the dictionary `get` function with `None` as default:

```
listofallergies = {'eggs': 1 , 'peanuts':2 ,'shellfish': 4 , 'strawberries':8 , 'tomatoes': 16 , 'chocolat':32 , 'pollen': 64 , 'cats': 128 }
listofallergies_inv = {val: key for key, val in listofallergies.items()}

def allergie(aller):

    return listofallergies_inv.get(aller, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code.

### Problem 1

The first problem I see is when you want to check if `aller` is a value in your dictionary by doing the following,

```
dict_ex = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
print(2 in dict_ex)
```

The result of this is false because python will only look for 2 in the dictionaries keys. Same thing as saying `2 in ['a','b','c']`

Instead, we can try and check if `aller` is in the dictionaries values specifically.

```
dict_ex = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
print(2 in dict_ex.values())
```

### Problem 2

Problem number 2 is when you find the key of `aller` using print `(listofallergies.keys(aller))`. `dict.keys()` does not take a value. To find a key using a value you can do the following.

```
dict_ex = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
aller = 2
for k,v in dict_ex.items():
    if v == aller:
        print(k)
```

This will give us `b`.

### Code

So your code fixed up...

```
def allergie(aller):
    listofallergies = {'eggs': 1 , 'peanuts':2 ,'shellfish': 4 , 'strawberries':8 , 'tomatoes': 16 , 'chocolat':32 , 'pollen': 64 , 'cats': 128 }
    if aller in listofallergies.values():
        for k,v in listofallergies.items():
            if v == aller:
                return k
    else:
        return None 
print (allergie(4))
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I recommend running this:

```
def allergie(aller):
    listofallergies = {'eggs': 1 , 'peanuts':2 ,'shellfish': 4 , 'strawberries':8 , 'tomatoes': 16 , 'chocolat':32 , 'pollen': 64 , 'cats': 128 }
    if aller in listofallergies:
        print("I am here")
        #print (listofallergies.keys(aller))    change this line
        return listofallergies[aller]
    else:
        return None 
print (allergie(4)) 

#output:
#None
```

This means the if block is never executed. Reason being you are checking if the value 4 is a `key` in the dictionary. Which it is not.

You can try the following

```
if aller in listofallergies.values()
    return listofallergies.keys()[listofallergies.values().index(aller)]
else:
return None
```

Alternatively, you xan use a dictionary that is the inverse of the on you have.

```
# if you want to create such a dictionary
alt_dict = {v: k for k, v in listofallergies.items()}

if aller in alt_dict:
    return alt_dict[aller]
else:
    return None
```